# angular 6 ng-select how to set item selected in drop down list by using template expression

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

In Angular 6 project, I am trying to use **ng-select** node package. I am facing the difficulty to set item selected in dropdown list while using template expression. Without template expression, I am able to set item selected in dropdown list.

I have created a demo project in stackblitz. Pls check the code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngselect-demo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**ng-select** is very flexible component regarding comparing elements in an array.

Here is the [findItem](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/blob/e007ba2b4641fcb111ad90b5c2f71db6bc6fd5f7/src/ng-select/items-list.ts#L94) function which is responsible for this comparison:

```
findItem(value: any): NgOption {
    let findBy: (item: NgOption) => boolean;
    if (this._ngSelect.compareWith) {
        findBy = item => this._ngSelect.compareWith(item.value, value)
    } else if (this._ngSelect.bindValue) {
        findBy = item => !item.children && this.resolveNested(item.value, this._ngSelect.bindValue) === value
    } else {
        findBy = item => item.value === value ||
            !item.children && item.label && item.label === this.resolveNested(value, this._ngSelect.bindLabel)
    }
    return this._items.find(item => findBy(item));
}
```

As you can see it follows the following rules:

1) Use `compareWith` function if provided, else

2) Use `bindValue` if provided, else

3) Use `bindLabel` if provided

In your first control that doesn't use template expression you passed `bindLabel` thus it works properly. If you add the same input to your second control it will works

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngselect-demo-duin8t?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

If you want to keep selected value as array of objects then I would recommend you using `compareWith` input

**html**

```
<ng-select 
  ...
  [compareWith]="compareWith"
```

**ts**

```
compareWith(item, selected) {
  return item.id === selected.id
}
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngselect-demo-ypbalv?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

otherwise use `bindValue`

Comment: thank you for the clear explanation. Your answer solved my problem.